# When sequences $a_{n}$ convergent and $b_{n}$ divergent, prove or disprove that $(a_{n} \cdot b_{n})$ is divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I would appreciate for someone to tell me whether my formalism here is right.

It is

$$a_{n}:=\frac{1}{n^6}, \ b_{n}:=n^5.$$

then it is trivial that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}=0, \ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^5= \infty.  $$

Now, especially it is to be seen that

$$(a_{n} \cdot b_{n})=\frac{1}{n^6} \cdot  n^5 = \frac{n^5}{n^6}=\frac{1}{n}.$$

where it is clear that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0.$$

Thus, the initial assumption is disproved. $\square$

Especially looking at the formalism here, is there any room for improvement? Please be very strict in your assessment since I want to learn how to do it right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a correct and neat argument.

Comment: Looks great! Minor details: (1) better would be to recall the result you'd like to prove in the body of the question and (2) $b$ should be replaced with $b_n$.

Comment: thanks a lot, I corrected it.

Comment: It depends on what $\,a_n\,$ converges to. If it is a non-zero limit, then it can be proved that $\,c_n:=a_n\,b_n\,$ is divergent. If it is zero, then the product sequence $\,c_n\,$ may or may not converge and you an give examples of both cases.